# Separar colunas de um dataset

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso separar em uma lista os tipos de colunas de um dataset em numérico e não numérico.

Por exemplo:

```py
def identifica_tipos(df):
    col_numerica = []
    for col in df.columns:
        if col.isnumeric:
            col_numerica.append(col)
```

Mas essa função que eu criei nao separa os dados , alguém tem alguma sugestão de funções que podem fazer isso ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez assim?

```
import numpy as np

new_df = df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)
```

Comment: funciona perfeitamente , obrigado e volte sempre !!